# Appending data on table view while scrolling down

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i am parsing data to a table view,there are hundreds of thousands of names in server page,i have two questions

1. Firstly i did (with help of php programmer) write all the server data in different pages in server side,and i put a "View more" button under the table view.When user click that,the page number will be increased to one and data on second page is shown to the table view.
   At that time i am loosing all the first page data on table view.
   How can i append previous data to table view when i click "View More".
2. If i write all the names in single page in server side, Can i call the data to TableView without memory problems
   (just like first 10rows and when i scroll down all other data are appending without memory problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@amar  I think its possible with  **UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];**

I am not sure,please check out and clarify...

Comment: Nithin that way you will be optimizing the way cells are shown i have issues with your data source as you said you are using a NSMutable array.In this case individual data might be small so that even lakhs of them do not create problem(which i doubt).What will you do if you have images?